# Electron app authentication works in dev but not after package with electron-builder

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authentication, electron, electron-builder

I am using azure authentication with vue-adal.
in dev mode, the authentication works fine,
when i run the .exe file, it doesn't, should i change anything in the authentication configuration to make this work?

i have tried to change the redirectUri to 'file///callback', i saw it somewhere, but i don't sure if this is the problem.

```
Vue.use(Adal, {
  config: {
    tenant: "c98fb553-0659-4746-aefd-c234de2a5cfc",
    clientId: "708b672d-6703-4449-911a-426170af3a07",
    redirectUri: "http://localhost:8080/",
    cacheLocation: "localStorage"
  },
  requireAuthOnInitialize: true,
  router: router
});
```

this is the error it shows me:

"ssoprobe:1 GET https://autologon.microsoftazuread-sso.com/c98fb553-0659-4746-aefd-c234de2a5cfc/winauth/ssoprobe?client-request-id=9ec584d5-54ca-4e13-b688-608681d6b2b4&_=1569426343845 401 (Unauthorized)"

in the development mode, the autologon works just fine.

i realy need your help, thanks in advance.